# Should there be a redirect from se.stackexchange.com?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, stackexchange

When trying to navigate to [Software Engineering Stack Exchange](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com), I frequently find myself typing `https://se.stackexchange.com` into my browser instead of `https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com`.

Would it be reasonable to ask for a redirect from `https://se.stackexchange.com` to `https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com`? Or is it just me?

(disclaimer: I happen to work for Stack, but I'm asking this as a user)

Comment: I put a [tag:status-review] on this. It seems like a good idea, but I honestly don't know if there are rules or guidelines for subdomains, or if there is a potential SE site that may also claim the "se" subdomain. It seems worthy of consideration and would let people use a full URL (rather than a shortener) in text-constrained environments.

Comment: Definitely worth considering :) I've added this to our list to address and will have updates here when there's more.

Comment: follow-up suggestion: [Should there be a shorter subdomain for the Software Engineering Stack Exchange?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9387/31260) (tl;dr - proposed domains swe, swen, or sweng since "se" seems to be off the table)

Answer (score 4):

As per the consensus reached on [this other discussion](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9389/117449), the following redirects are now in place:

- http://swe.stackexchange.com/ and https://swe.stackexchange.com/ now redirect to https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/
- http://meta.swe.stackexchange.com/ now redirects to https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/

Comment: It looks like since the URLs for Meta sites changed from `meta.[sitename]` to `[sitename].meta`, a redirect was not added for `https://swe.meta.stackexchange.com/`. We should add one. (For reference, the HTTPS URL https://meta.swe.stackexchange.com/ doesn't actually load at all, instead showing a privacy error – since HTTPS doesn't work for the `meta.[sitename]` format. The HTTP version of that URL, http://meta.swe.stackexchange.com/, does properly redirect.)

Comment: I'd noticed this too, @V2Blast, and made the devs aware of it last week ;)

Comment: Was pointed to https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/299088/208518 as our official stance on this issue ;)