# Should there be a shorter subdomain for the Software Engineering Stack Exchange?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, stackexchange

[A previous feature request](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9131/should-there-be-a-redirect-from-se-stackexchange-com) has come up for attention by the development team. The idea is that "softwareengineering.stackexchange.com" can be quite long and annoying in the cases where people have to type it into their browser.

The development team is offering a shorter subdomain for redirect, however "se" as a subdomain is off the table since the abbreviation "SE" is also used for the Stack Exchange network as a whole.

A few possible options are swe, swen, or sweng. Another option, of course, is that a shorter  subdomain doesn't make sense (either in general or because se is off the table).

Thoughts from the community?

Comment: Seems like an insignificant optimisation when we still have to type in stackexchange. Would make more sense in the context of an overall URL minification initiative, for example swe.stackx.com

Comment: I think Stack Exchange, Inc. should just buy Sweden. Then we can have https://swe.se/.

Comment: softwareeng could work

Comment: Isn't this redundant in the age where a browser remembers URLs ?

Comment: Now since the feature is there, it might be a good idea to make the "Share" button use it. I sometimes use the Share button for getting a short link to be pasted into the comment section, where short links might help not to exceed the 600 characters limit.

Comment: @DocBrown Yes - I'm about to make a meta post to put that on the radar of the dev teams.

Answer (score 24):

I support swe because 3 is less than 4.

Comment: I support swe because that's the standard acronym/initialism (depending on how you say it) in the industry

Answer (score 2):

I was thinking about [programmer.stackexchange.com](https://programmer.stackexchange.com/)
Ohhh wait.

Comment: I still consider this alias canonical because `softwareengineering` has too long of a common prefix with `softwarerecs`.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps an orthogonal solution would be better?

I would love to see navigation buttons connecting related SE sites.
We have "Hot Network Questions" but we do not even have simple buttons to jump sideways from overflow to meta or "unix and linux" or whereever.

I either go to my profile and then to my network profile
or to my inbox or reputation changes to jump between sites I use regularly.

Comment: This is a different feature request with a different use case. In 2020, there was already a feature request for a shorter domain that the development teams have accepted. This is also more of a network-wide request, so it would be better posted on Meta Stack Exchange.

Answer (score -1):

I'd like to vote on **s17g.stackexchange**