# The share button on posts should be updated to reflect the existence of the shorter domain names

Tags: feature-request, status-deferred, site-attributes, site-promotion

[On July 21, the `swe` subdomain was added for Software Engineering](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9131/4), making `swe.stackexchange.com` a redirect to `softwareengineering.stackexchange.com`. Now that there is a shorter URL, this should be the URL that appears when using the share button on posts.

[Doc Brown points out](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9387/should-there-be-a-shorter-subdomain-for-the-software-engineering-stack-exchange#comment28923_9387) that one use case for this is when including links to other questions or answers in text length-constrained fields, such as comments on the SE network. Comments are limited to 600 characters, so eliminating 16 characters from the URL automatically would give commenters extra space.

Comment: Not seeing much being done about this. Is there a form to fill out or a street to protest on?

Comment: @candied_orange The [meta-tag:status-review] tag should put it in a queue for review. Tomorrow, I'll ping someone on the CM team to see what the deal is if they don't respond before then.

Comment: Thank goodness. This is not protest friendly weather.

Comment: @Thomas, is this still under review?  Or do we have some action (or inaction!) on its way?

Comment: @TobySpeight I will follow up. The status-review tag should put it up for review, so I'd have expected at least a comment from staff by now.

Comment: Since the functionality isn't broken, this rates relatively low in the priority scale, and is in our backlog. Updated the status tag to reflect that.

Answer (score 5):

While we're at it can we do the same for meta share links? Likely first need to get its certificate worked out so that

https://meta.swe.stackexchange.com/a/9397#comment28925_9397

will work as well as

http://meta.swe.stackexchange.com/a/9397#comment28925_9397

does. <sub>Maybe also get it to stop striping out the comment info.</sub>

Comment: If the redirect is losing fragment identifiers, that's not something the server can fix - those are entirely client-side.

Comment: @TobySpeight doesn't the client-side code I run come from the server? Or are you trying to say it's a bug in my browsers code?

Comment: I assumed that the redirection is a HTTP 301 response (Moved Permanently), rather than some client-side script, so that it will work for everyone, rather than just those willing to enable scripts.  That shouldn't cause loss of the fragment identifier, if your browser is behaving.  If my assumption is wrong, I'll sit corrected....

Answer (score 3):

Thus I vote to make the code monkey<sup>[1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qYodWEKCuGg)</sup> change this once to save the multitude from changing it every time.